# other than max value, replace all value to 0 in each column (pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df which I want to replace values that are not the max value for each column to 0.

code:

```
data = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [3, 5, 1],
    "C": [9, 0, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

sample df:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  3   9
1  2  5   0
2  3  1   1
```

result trying to get:

```
   A  B   C
0  0  0   9
1  0  5   0
2  3  0   0
```

kindly advise.
many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df!=df.max()] = 0
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  0  9
1  0  5  0
2  3  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with compare `max` values :

```
df = df.where(df.eq(df.max()), 0)
print(df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  9
1  0  5  0
2  3  0  0
```